# Stopping an ObjectAnimation when a button is released

Tags: java, android

I have an objcectAnimation that is meant to move the player down when the button is being held, and stop when it is released, I've tried using separate MotionEvent's to see if that was the problem but it didn't solve anything. I don't know if it helps, but the buttons are imageView objects
My code is

```
        //start the animation when the button is pressed down, and stop it when the button is released
    moveDOWN.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(player, "translationY", player.getX()+1F);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                animation.start();
            }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    animation.cancel();
                }
                return true;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `animation.cancel()` try using this:

```java
v.getAnimation().cancel();
v.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: I tried to run it like this on my physical device and when i released the button, the program crashes